# Does multiple apps work on multiple cores if launched in fork_mode with pm2?

Tags: node.js, cpu, pm2, cpu-cores

I created a steam bot script which i use for 3 steam accounts. To run them i starts the same script with pm2 in fork mode passing an argument which is the bot id. Do all of the 3 processes run on the same core or can they use the second core as well since they are separated processes? If they run on a single core, starting the script like "pm2 start script.js -i number of bots" and using the worker id as the bot id could make them run an all cores? I'm not sure if this will work though, I'm still learning about node js cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pm2 start script.js -i N` will run N node processes on N different cores.
It is called `cluster mode` and it is explained in pm2 documentation.
For more details, you can search the documentation: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Comment: So if i start multiple processes using different arguments in fork mode all 3 of them will run on the first core of the machine?

Comment: No, pm2 will spread them across all of your cores. But I suggest creating ecosystem file and running them all with one command: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/